# How can I get the character at the cursor position in a multibyte aware manner?

Tags: vimscript, unicode, cursor

Consider the following line:

```
€   €
```

This file is encoded in UTF-8 and between the two Euro marks is a Tab character (the Stack Exchange software expands this to spaces). The byte value is:

```
e2 82 ac 09 e2 82 ac 0a
```

In my script I would like to get the character under the cursor.

Vim has several useful functions for dealing with strings in a multibyte-aware fashion, but getting the cursor position seems difficult:

- `col('.')` will return the byte position. So for the tab it will return `4` rather than `2`.
- `virtcol('.')` *almost* works, but will expand tabs, so this isn't a true character position either.
- All other functions behave as one of the two above.

What I have so far is:

```
fun! Getchar()
    let l:line = substitute(getline('.'), '\t', repeat(' ', &tabstop), 'g')
    return strcharpart(l:line, virtcol('.') - 1, 1)
endfun
nnoremap GG :echo Getchar()<CR>
```

Which *almost* works, but not for the above example since the displayed width is less than `&tabstop` spaces long.

Comment: I would simply use `yl` plus some saving and restoring of register to take care of.

Comment: Me too, @ChristianBrabandt. I'd put it into register `"`, which I don't use (my default is `+`/`*`). But you can use any one that won't bother you. Examples:
`nnoremap q :<C-u>exe 'norm! ""yl' \| echo @"<CR>`
`nnoremap q ""yl:echo @"<CR>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We discussed it less then 10 days ago [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5t08uo/vimscript_unicode/).

One solution is `matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'.col('.').'c.')` which doesn't mess with any register.

I've put the [resulting functions](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/encoding.vim#L116) (we can ask for the characters before, or after the cursor) in my vimscript library along with other functions on the subject.

Comment: Also note that we must not use `virtcol` here but actually `col` since the regexp will be `\%1c.` where `1` is an example interpolated col. If you have a virtcol value you must use `\%1v.` instead (`:h ordinary-atom`)

Comment: Isn't this highly inefficient for very long lines? `getline('.')` returns the entire line no matter how long it is.

Comment: @Flux, it depends on what you're doing. If you just test a character before expanding an abbreviation or something like that, you won't notice anything. Control statements (loops, if...) are where we waste most of our time in vimscript language pre v9.

Answer (score 4):

The following works and is faster than the `matchstr()` solution:

```
fun! Getchar()
  return strcharpart(strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 1), 0, 1)
endfun
nnoremap GG :echo Getchar()<CR>
```

See my question [Reliably get the character at a byte index in a string](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19694/reliably-get-the-character-at-a-byte-index-in-a-string).

Comment: Best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the patch [8.2.2324](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2324), you can use the `charcol()` function in a `:def` function:

```
def Getchar(): string
    return getline('.')[charcol('.') - 1]
enddef
nnoremap GG :echom Getchar()<CR>
```

It works because in Vim9 script, inside a string slice, indexes match characters, not bytes.  This is documented at [`:h expr-[]`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-%5B%5D):

> In Vim9 script:
> If expr8 is a String this results in a String that contains the expr1'th
> single character from expr8.  To use byte indexes use |strpart()|.

You don't have to write a new `:def` function to leverage this syntax.  You can include it in an existing legacy function, using the `:vim9` command modifier:

```
fun! Getchar()
    vim9 return getline('.')[charcol('.') - 1]
endfun
nnoremap GG :echo Getchar()<CR>
```

`:vim9` requires the patch [8.2.2511](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2511).

During my limited tests, `charcol()` + `:vim9` in a legacy function was a bit faster than `strcharpart()` (between 5% and 10% faster).  `charcol()` in a `:def` function was about twice as fast.

---

To get the character after the cursor:

```
vim9 echom getline('.')[charcol('.')]
```

To get the character before the cursor:

```
vim9 echom charcol('.') == 1 ? '' : getline('.')[charcol('.') - 2]
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
vim9 echom getline('.')->strpart(0, col('.') - 1)[-1]
```

---

If you have the patch [8.2.2344](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2344), which provides the [`slice()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#slice()) function, then you can get away without `:vim9`.

To get the character *under* the cursor:

```
echom getline('.')->slice(charcol('.') - 1, charcol('.'))
```

The character *after* the cursor:

```
echom getline('.')->slice(charcol('.'), charcol('.') + 1)
```

The character *before* the cursor:

```
echom getline('.')->slice(charcol('.') - 2, charcol('.') - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this in my plugin.

```
let char = matchstr(getline('.')[col('.') - 1 :], '^.')
```