# expand('<cWORD>') returns empty string in inoremap

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'm trying to define an insert mapping like this:

```
inoremap <expr><buffer> ; (Test(expand('<cWORD>'))).";"
```

in which the `Test` function is defined as:

```
func! Test(a)
    echom "cword: "."\"".a:a."\""
endfunction
```

For example, if the current position of the cursor is like:

```
apple|
```

When I type `;`, I'm expecting a message saying: `cword: "apple"`.

But currently, I can only get an empty result like: `cword: ""`

The question is why does the `expand()` function here always returns an empty string?

Comment: I'm using gvim version 8.0

Comment: in insert mode the cursor is really located here: `apple[ ]`.  so it's not over the word at all.

Comment: @Mass Oh, okay then. So there's a specific way to retrieve the word "before" the cursor? Or I need to manually split the word from `getline(.)`?

Comment: if you leave insert mode, the cursor should be on the last letter and then `cword` should be valid again.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, if you stay in insert mode, the cursor will be one character too far for `expand('<cword>')` to return anything useful.

That's why a long time ago I wrote [these functions](http://hermitte.free.fr/vim/general.php#expl_words_tools), now [part of lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/ui.vim#L52). Typically you'd be interested in

```
function! lh#ui#GetCurrentWord()
  let c = col ('.')-1
  let l = line('.')
  let ll = getline(l)
  let ll1 = strpart(ll,0,c)
  let ll1 = matchstr(ll1,'\S*$')
  if strlen(ll1) == 0
    return ll1
  else
    let ll2 = strpart(ll,c,strlen(ll)-c+1)
    let ll2 = strpart(ll2,0,match(ll2,'$\|\s'))
    return ll1.ll2
  endif
endfunction
```

The code is quite old and could be simplified.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted it and cannot undo...

Comment: The variable names are confusing at best, incidentally.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the answer to [another question about multibyte-aware character at current position](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/how-can-i-get-the-character-at-the-cursor-position-in-a-multibyte-aware-manner), consider using the `:help /\%v` zero-width atom to perform a string match.

```
let l:wordBeforeCursor = matchstr(getline('.'), '\k\+\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v')
let l:WORDContainingCursor = matchstr(getline('.'), '\S*\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S*')
```

The first uses `\k` to match `iskeyword` characters (like `<cword>`) and will return `'apple'` if your cursor is in `call Foo(apple|jack)`.  The second uses `\S` to match non-space (like `<cWORD>`) and will return `Foo(apple|jack)`.

Note that `<cword>` is forward-looking, and skips space between the cursor and the next word, e.g. `expand('<cword>')` on `apple| pie` will return `'pie'` rather than empty string.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!