# How to jump to the last non-blank character in soft wrapped long line in vim?

Tags: vimrc

I have those setting in .vimrc

```
setlocal textwidth=0 wrap formatoptions=tc2n linebreak
noremap <buffer> j gj
noremap <buffer> k gk
noremap <buffer> $ g$
noremap <buffer> ^ g^
noremap <buffer> 0 g0

nnoremap <buffer> dd g0vg$D
nnoremap <buffer> D g0vg$D

nnoremap I g^i
nnoremap A g$BEa

nnoremap V g0vg$
```

But I found `g$` stop at the last character including space in vim, where in vscode-neovim, using the same .vimrc, `g$` will stop at the last non-blank character.
How to get the same `g$` behavior in vim? Or, how to jump to last non-black character in vim? so that I don't have to map `A` as `g$BEa`, since it sometimes don't jump to the location I want, if the last character is `"`.

`g$` in vim
[image]

`g$` in vsocde with vscode-neovim plugin(I have proved there is a space after the character)
[image]

Comment: Your vscode plugin appears to be broken. Better fix it than spread the disease to working editors, no?

Comment: I created https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/12593 for this

Answer (score 0):

I have written a dirty solution that work as describe.
But if you can provide built-in functionality that work exactly is appreciated.

```
function! IsBlank()
    normal! g$
    let char = getline(".")[col(".") - 1]
    if char == "\t" || char == " "
        normal! gel
        startinsert
    else
        startinsert!
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Note that `getline(".")[col(".") - 1]` won't work correct as it will use byte offsets rather than character offsets. So if you have an UTF-8 multibyte character it won't work as expected. See [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11476/51). Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't anything built in to Vim for this, but you can remap `g$` (and/or `$`) to backup a bit if it lands on a space:

```
fun! s:gdollar()
    normal! g$
    while strcharpart(strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 1), 0, 1) == ' '
        if col('.') == 1
            break
        endif
        normal! h
    endwhile
endfun
nnoremap <silent> g$ :call <SID>gdollar()<CR>
```

This will actually skip *all* spaces; change the `while` and `endwhile` to `if` and `endif` to only move back once (you can also remove the `if col('.') == 1` then). You may also want to check for tab (`"\t"`) perhaps; I'm not entirely sure how the VSCode plugin behaves.

Please note that `nnoremap` are "non recursive mappings", which means that they will always use the built-in functionality for keys rather than anything you redefined. Usually this is what you want, but here:

```
nnoremap g$ :call <SID>gdollar()<CR>
nnoremap $  g$
```

Means that `$` will call the *built-in* version of `g$`, rather than your custom version. You will have to either use `nmap` or call that function in every mapping where you want the new behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since Vim patch [v9.0.1753](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v9.0.1753) you can now use `g<end>` to jump to the last non-blank char on a line.